# How do "from a_module import *" using imp module

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I use the `imp` module to manually look for a particular module:

```python
import imp

module_found = imp.find_module('a_module', ['/path/to/my/module'])

a_module = imp.load_module('a_module', *module_found)
```

Now, how can I import everything in the local scope as if I would have done `from a_module import *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was so simple I actually didn't even tried:

```python
import imp

module_found = imp.find_module('a_module', ['/path/to/my/module'])

a_module = imp.load_module('a_module', *module_found)

from a_module import *
```

I simply had to execute `from a_module import *` after `imp.load_module()` and everything was loaded properly! :)